# How to get value of a dynamically created component in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble getting value of dynamically generate component. I am able to target the child component. However I am not being to get the value of the child component. Not sure what I am missing. The set-up is little bit wired because I am using object of Array (using Firebase for database). Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/g3nscf0h/

```
// Javascript jsx
<script type="text/jsx">
     var data = {
        a: 'all',
        b: 'ball',
        c: 'cat'
    };



var MyComp = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return{
        data: this.props.data
    };
},

handleClick: function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.target.value)
},


render: function() {
    var o = this.props.data;

    return(
        <div className="words">
            {Object.keys(o).map(function(k) {
                return (
                    <div key={k} className="word" onClick={this.handleClick} value={o[k]}> {o[k]} </div>
                );
            }.bind(this))}
        </div>

    );
}
});



React.render(<MyComp data={data} /> , document.getElementById('container'));


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - remove spaces before and after internal `{o[k]}`. Look at your resulting markup, there are three `span` elements and you are trying to get the `value` property of clicked span. Second - I suggest to get attribute value with `getAttribute` method. I have modified your fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/g3nscf0h/5/

```
handleClick: function(e){
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'));
}
//...
<div key={k} className="word" onClick={this.handleClick} data-value={o[k]}>{o[k]}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks much for the solution. And also pointing out the exprea space. I wasn't able to figure out why I was getting spans!!!